# How much does glider insurance typically cost in the UK?

Tags: glider, uk, insurance

I (and my colleague from the club) plan to buy K8B glider. Does anyone know how much the insurance can be? We are both "just solo" pilots in our 50s. All insurance companies require details we do not want to provide as we did not purchase the glider yet. I am just curious if it is a few hundred or a few grand a year?

Answer (score 3):

Just now,  one of the insurance companies has called me back.

They told me that the insurance premium will be between £290 - £790 depending on the cover details and the equipment insured.

Comment: [Answering own question is encouraged](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer), no need making it a community-wiki.

Comment: Per year? Does it not depend on the amount of flying?

Comment: @Zeus That is what a guy from the insurance company told me.